# YARN log aggregation on aws emr - expecting one single container file but still find multiple

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to aggregate all the container logs for an application to a single file for better debugging the spark application.

I configured yarn log-aggregation as suggested by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html. From the docs, "Log aggregation (Hadoop 2.x) compiles logs from all containers for an individual application into a single file. " -> this sounds like what I need.

I created an emr cluster with:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.log-aggregation-enable": "true",
      "yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds": "-1",
      "yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir": "s3:\/\/mybucket\/emr_log"
    }
  }
]
```

I verify the above configuration is in the yarn-site.xml on the new cluster. But submitting jobs to the cluster, I am still seeing multiple container logs when looking at the s3 log directory.

I expected to see one file under s3://mybucket/emr_log/cluster_id/containers/application_id/stderr.gz
But I still found several container directories under the application_id directories:
Ex:
s3://mybucket/emr_log/cluster_id/containers/application_id/container_XXXXXXXX_0001_01_000001/stderr.gz
s3://mybucket/emr_log/cluster_id/containers/application_id/container_XXXXXXXX_0001_01_000002/stderr.gz
s3://mybucket/emr_log/cluster_id/containers/application_id/container_XXXXXXXX_0001_01_000003/stderr.gz

Am I missing anything? Is it possible to have one single container log for one application?

Comment: The option is not working as you expected. It will not aggregate each log for the applications.

Comment: @Lamanus Thanks for the response. Do you know if it is possible to aggregate all the container logs into one file? What is this option actually doing then?